# How can I disable Ctrl+Alt+F10 on 14.04/Gnome/Compiz

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz

I get the standard behaviour when I press this combination which sort of switches off the display and I know that I can go back to it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> but the IDE I use has a pretty useful action fired under that shortcut which I want to take place rather than the display going off.

PS. I am on Gnome with Compiz.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the entry from Keyboard shortcuts under settings.
It can be changed using the command ***gsettings***. Also, you can download dconf-editor to change the configurations.